# How can I format point data labels in scatter chart using Google Data Studio?

Tags: charts, looker-studio

When I'm using Excel I can insert a label on my scatter chart data points, but Google Data Studio only wants me to change the color of the points, I not found any documentation about how insert labels on the points, anyone has idea?

Answer (score 0):

Its at the top of the Style section

[image]

Comment: Do you happen to know how to format the colour of these labels as well? I am struggling in general with the ability to customise data labels, as well as axes labels..

Comment: No. Data Studio recently released an update that automatically contrasts label colours but generally they aren't very customisable which creates a lot of formatting issues